# how to add id of document in filds firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

i have firestore database where is a field which call idDoc after create a document i want to add a document id in idDoc i do this function

```
    fun updateNotesDocId(userId: String){
        notesChannnelsCollectionRef.document(userId)
            .collection("notes")
            .document(notesChannnelsCollectionRef.document().id)
            .update(mapOf(notesChannnelsCollectionRef.document().id to "idDoc"))
```

and this code doesnt work. 
I swapped everything.

**whats i want in photo**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `document()` with no parameters will give you a DocumentReference with a different random ID.  You will want to just call it once, remember the result, and reuse it.

```
        val ref = notesChannnelsCollectionRef.document()
        notesChannnelsCollectionRef.document(userId)
            .collection("notes")
            .document(ref.id)
            .set(mapOf("idDoc" to ref.id))
```

Comment: oh maybe i will show myself is stupid i integrate your code in my code and this doesn`t work maybe its because a ```private val notesChannnelsCollectionRef = firestoreInstance.collection("notesChannels")```

Comment: i have problem with apdate 
``` 
NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/graduete-work/databases/(default)/documents/notesChannels/kWvT6j7ObVfjVDy2iE2nITwep0V2/notes/notesChannels
```

Comment: set() delete all fields and set one "idDoc"

Comment: Are you generating a new document or not?  Please edit the question to be clear about what you want to happen.  If you are just updating an existing document, then you need to know its ID.  You can't call update() without knowing that a document exists.